# Is there a limit on transactional data Sharepoint can handle?

Tags: performance

We have a SharePoint application developed in SharePoint 2013 for a hospital and   the application has around 10k transactions/day.

I understand that Sharepoint is not a good candidate for transactional systems and there might be real need to migrate the application to more native web application with relevant database.

Some of the lists in this application have around 1 million items and there are a lot of relations between the tables.

My questions are

- Is there a limit of transactions handled by Sharepoint?
- How badly will the performance be affected if transactions are increased?
- Is migrating the system to other platforms good in a long run?

Appreciate any suggestions and advice.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Is there a limit of transactions handled by Sharepoint?

- There's not a specific limit , There are several factors and assumptions that take part in an estimation. it's recommended to not increase more than 500 Concurrent users (transactions) per WFE server and also it's based on server Hardware Specification . (Note : For `IIS` it's 1000 Per Web Server)

Read more about [Capacity management and sizing overview for SharePoint Server 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff758647.aspx)

How badly will the performance be affected if transactions are increased?

- More Transaction - More Slowness and to overcome that you need to scale out WFE Servers. and scale up the current servers specification.

Is migrating the system to other platforms good in a long run?

- I agree with you that SharePoint is not suitable for High-level business (more transaction)
- But also the decision of migrating to another platform will have a high risk and will take more time , and will be more costly than improving the current environment . (also this depends on the type and functionality of your current system)
- This decision has a risk and should be taken based on your requirements.